# Every continuous function $f$ on the unit sphere (shell) has a point $p$ such that $f(p)=f(-p)$

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, connectedness

**The Question:**

Define the subset of $\Bbb R^3$

$$S=\{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3: x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \}$$

Suppose that $f:S \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a continuous function. Prove that there exists $p \in S$ such that $f(p)=f(-p)$.

---

**My Attempt:**

I don't know where to start really. I feel that the following facts might be useful:

- Intermediate Value Theorem
- $f:S \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is continuous and $S$ is connected $\implies$ $f(S)$ is connected
- Path connected $\implies$ connected

Any hints as to how I should tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem. That states that if
$f:S^n\to\Bbb R^n$ is continuous, then there is a $p$ with $f(p)=f(-p)$.

In our case just look for a point on $S^1=\{(x,y,0):x^2+y^2=1\}\subset S^2$
with $f(p)=f(-p)$. In this case, Borsuk-Ulam is quite elementary. Just
consider $g(t)=f(\cos t,\sin t,0)-f(-\cos t,-\sin t,0)$. All you need is
the Intermediate Value Theorem to ensure that $g$ has a zero.

Comment: Nice answer! If you may take Borsuk-Ulam for granted (which I doubt), combining $f$ with an embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$, e.g. $x\mapsto(x,0)$, seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If f is continuous, then $T: p\mapsto f(p) - f(-p)$ is continuous. By symmetry $T(p) = - T(-p)$. Since images of connected sets under continuous functions are connected this yields that the image of T is a symmetric interval  containing $0$.